# User can press more than one UIButtons on quiz app

Tags: iphone, button

i am building a quiz app
which is 1 question and four possible answers
data is stored in a plist file
everything works great a tester just noticed though that during  a question he could actually hit all answers before the end of the timer
which is a problem
each button has the above code

```
-(IBAction)firstbtn_Click:(id)sender
{
    //first_button_clicked
    [self.btnOne addTarget:self action:@selector(answerWithTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self answerWithTag:self.btnOne.tag];

}
```

any ideas??

Comment: You could disable all other buttons once one is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable all the buttons once one button has been clicked. If you disable all the other buttons except the one which has been clicked, you can continue clicking the one which has already been clicked and action can repeat. Create a common method like this.

```
   -(void)disableButtons
    {
        [self.btnOne setEnabled:NO];
        [self.btnTwo setEnabled:NO];
        [self.btnThree setEnabled:NO];
        [self.btnFour setEnabled:NO];
    }
```

Call that method in all the method actions like this.

```
-(IBAction)firstbtn_Click:(id)sender
{
    //first_button_clicked
    [self.btnOne addTarget:self action:@selector(answerWithTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self answerWithTag:self.btnOne.tag];

    [self disableButtons];
}
```

I am not sure exactly what the method of `answerWithTag:` is doing but going by what it says, you are setting the target of `answerWithTag:` for button clicks unnecessarily. The problem is that, if you had not disabled the buttons, then in the next button call, two times your method of `answerWithTag:` would have been called.

So you can consider reducing your function to

```
-(IBAction)firstbtn_Click:(id)sender
{
    //first_button_clicked
    [self answerWithTag:self.btnOne.tag];
    [self disableButtons];
}
```

Moreover, if the actions for all the buttons are same and you wish to just pass the answer, try to set the text of the answer on the button, and you can do something like this.

```
-(IBAction)anyButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [self answerWithText:[button text]];
    [self disableButtons];
}
```

Give the action of all the buttons as `anyButtonClicked`. This would reduce the length of your code and will make it more managable.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.just to ask this clear..i put all the code you mentioned to all inactions for each button?or i misunderstood?

Comment: just before i saw your answer i tried something..mayb its not correct but seems it works...for example first button clicked i use:
        [self.btnTwo setEnabled:NO];
        [self.btnThree setEnabled:NO];
        [self.btnFour setEnabled:NO]; and for every other button the same and notb using the specific button number below...it seems that it works..ill try the new solution you provided as well

Comment: thank you so much just did....i have another question posted here regarding uiswitch if you can help thanks once again!